# Reading DTMF from called party after some time in call in asterisk

Tags: asterisk, ivr, dtmf

I am trying to make a system where user1 makes a call to user2 and after few minutes of conversation user1 asks user2 to press some key and user1 one should be able to read this DTMF sent by called party.

`Read()` command reads the DTMF from caller, hence is not an appropriate option.
`D([called][:callin])` option in `Dial()` command can do this but it is used in Dial command and hence can only send/receive DTMF at the time of call is answered, Not after few minutes into the call, hence not again appropriate option.

Please help me by suggesting something which can be used to achieve above scenario. Let me know if more info is required.

Answer (score 0):

You can check features.conf, that can suite your need

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+config+features.conf

Also you can write c/c++ app to collect data

There are no other way collect dtmf in bridged call.